# New text area not storing data on save in WP Settings General

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a text area in WordPress general settings, which allows a disclaimer or other info to show at the bottom of each page of the website template.

It works fine using the input tag, however when I change to textarea it will not store the data on save.

I have been searching online, but haven't found the right solution.

Here is the current code I am using:

```
<?php
$new_general_setting_disclaimer = new new_general_setting_disclaimer();

class new_general_setting_disclaimer {
    function new_general_setting_disclaimer( ) {
        add_filter( 'admin_init' , array( &$this , 'register_fields' ) );
    }
    function register_fields() {
        register_setting( 'general', 'disclaimer', 'esc_attr' );
        add_settings_field('disclaimer', '<label for="disclaimer">'.__('Website Disclaimer' , 'disclaimer' ).'</label>' , array(&$this, 'fields_html') , 'general' );
    }
    function fields_html() {
        $value = get_option( 'disclaimer' );
        echo '<textarea id="disclaimer" name="disclaimer" cols="50" rows="5" value="'. $value .'" /></textarea>';
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if you need more info.